# For continuous, monotonically-increasing $f$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, prove $\sum_{k=1}^{10}f(k/10)+f^{-1}(k/10)\leq 99/10$

Tags: analysis, functions, inequality, contest-math

A question from Leningrad Mathematical Olympiad 1991:

> Let $f$ be continuous and monotonically increasing, with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.
>   Prove that:$$
> \text{f}\left( \frac{1}{10} \right) +\text{f}\left( \frac{2}{10} \right) +...+\text{f}\left( \frac{9}{10} \right) +\text{f}^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{10} \right) +\text{f}^{-1}\left( \frac{2}{10} \right) +...+\text{f}^{-1}\left( \frac{9}{10} \right) \leqslant \frac{99}{10}
> $$

I tried to express them in areas to find inequalities but failed.

Comment: A continuous and monotonically increasing function need not have an inverse.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It's possible the original Russian specified $f$ was monotonically *strictly* increasing. I don't envy the translators.

Comment: I don’t know if you can make a rigorous proof out of this but note that the graph of $f^{-1}$ is the image of $f$ in $y=x$.

Comment: $\frac{99}{10}$ or $\frac{99}{100}$ ?

Comment: See here: https://imgur.com/a/NAsePo4

Comment: @Cesareo The choice $f(x)=x$ achieves $9$, so it can't be $\frac{99}{100}$.

Comment: @camhunter  In the title the upper limit on $k$ needs to be 9 (not 10 ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to convert @LeBlanc's comment into an answer:

For $1\le i\le 9$ let $S_i$ denote the rectangle with base $x\in[\tfrac{i}{10},\,\tfrac{i+1}{10})$ and height $f(\tfrac{i}{10})$, and let $P_i$ denote the rectangle with base $y\in[\tfrac{i}{10},\,\tfrac{i+1}{10})$ and height $f^{-1}(\tfrac{i}{10})$. These $18$ areas don't overlap; $S:=\bigcup_iS_i$ is a subset of the area under $y=f(x)$, while $P:=\bigcup_iP_i$ is a subset of the area in the square $[0,\,1]^2$ above $y=f(x)$. What's more, any point in any $P_i$ has $x\ge\frac{1}{10}$, while any point in any $S_i$ has $y\ge\frac{1}{10}$. Thus $$P\cup S\subseteq[0,\,1)^2\setminus[0,\,\tfrac{1}{10})^2.$$The desired sum is $10$ times the area of $P\cup S$, completing the proof.

LeBlanc's diagram includes the above exposition; hopefully the link will work indefinitely.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Note: In the title of the question the upper limit of $k$ needs to be 9.**

When $y=f(x)$ is monotonically increasing in domain $D$ then area under the curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=f^{-1}(x)$ is more that those of the resprctive rectangles below them.
Also the sum the area integrals
$$A=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)~ dx+\int_{y_1}^{y_2} f^{-1} (y)~ dy = x_2 y_2 -x_1 y_1$$ 
Here $f: [0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$. Let the domain be divided into 10 strips of width $1/10$. Let  $S$ denotes area under the rectangles of equal width. Then
$$S= \frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=1}^{9} [f(k/10)+ f^{-1}(k/10)] \le \sum_{k=1}^{9} \frac{(k+1)^2-(k)^2}{100}= \sum_{k=1}^{9}\frac{2k+1}{100}=\frac{99}{10}$$ $$\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{10} [f(k/10)+ f^{-1}(k/10)] \le \frac{99}{10}. $$ 
As $S$ is the sum of area of rectangles below the curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=f^{-1}(x)$.